# Missing dependencies lua-cjson >= 2.1.0 for installing fblualib?

Tags: lua, torch

When installing fblualib, encountered the following error:

```
Missing dependencies for fbluaunit:
lua-cjson >= 2.1.0

^CWarning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed     fetching manifest for http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks - Error fetching file: Failed downloading http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/manifest

Error: Could not satisfy dependency: lua-cjson >= 2.1.0

Missing dependencies for fbluaunit:
lua-cjson >= 2.1.0

^CWarning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks - Error fetching file: Failed downloading http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/manifest

Error: Could not satisfy dependency: lua-cjson >= 2.1.0
    cmake -E make_directory build &&
    cd build &&
    cmake -DROCKS_PREFIX=/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1 \
          -DROCKS_LUADIR=/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lua \
          -DROCKS_LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lib \
          .. &&
    make

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Torch", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Torch" with any of
  the following names:

    TorchConfig.cmake
    torch-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Torch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If     "Torch"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/fblualib-build.0APMyV/fblualib/fblualib/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

I have tried to using my luarocks to install lua-cjson and when the installation complete it showed:

```
lua-cjson 2.1.0-1 is now built and installed in /home/XXXXXXXXX/torch/install/ (license: MIT)
```

I think it was installed, but when I installed fblualib again cause the same error.
How to overcome it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I checked, it was network fault. After set right network environment, all went smoothly.